# Can't open a downloaded file from Chrome/Firefox Browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, clickonce, file-association, norton

We are using a Clickonce application with a registered file association. We are downloading a *.foo file and it should open the ClickOnce program when clicking the file. It will open the program correctly when going to the folder in Windows and double clicking the file. However, when downloading the file in Chrome or Firefox, we are unable to start the program by clicking the downloaded file in the browser view - it looks like its loading for a second but then nothing happens; no error or message. We can only do it by opening the file location and clicking it there. Also, it seems to be working in Internet Explorer, and it will open the program by clicking it on the list of downloads within the browser.

The computer is running Windows Vista, and has Norton 360 installed. We tried disabling Download Intelligence, and all web-related settings on that, but it didn't seem to work.

Any ideas why Chrome and Firefox would be blocking this file from being opened, while Internet Explorer works fine?

Comment: pretty sure you have to install an extension in chrome for it to work. chrome://extensions/

Answer (score 0):

For **Chrome**, we use this extension: [Chrome Web Store: Windows Remix ClickOnce Handler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/windows-remix-clickonce-h/dgpgholdldjjbcmpeckiephjigdpikan).

For **Firefox**, The ClickOnce team is gauging interest for a new plugin. Please reply to the thread over at [github:Microsoft/dotnet/issues/185](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/185#issuecomment-296322293) to voice your interest.